# How do I normalize mysql data in php and group matching data into separate groups?

Tags: php, mysql, grouping, normalization

I have a hotel database having a table which contains a column consisting of phone numbers separated by commas.
I want to group matching phone numbers such that the hotels having same phone numbers (eg: a toll-free number common to a hotel chain) fall in same group id.
Ex: A has phone numbers 1,2; B has 2,3 and C has 3,4. Then all of them should be in same group.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very generic question with too few details to allow a good answer or worth the time spent to create a good answer. Please add more details like some table designs that you have or have tried. SQL that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly. You will want to create two new tables;

```
PhoneNumbers
phone_id int auto-increment - Will hold the phone numbers unique Id
telephone varchar(30) - Will hold the phone number itself

Hotel_PhoneNumbers
hotel_id int - The id of the hotel
phone_id int - The id of the phone number
```

You will need to create a PHP script to pull all hotels out of your database, loop through each hotel and explode the phone number field into an array. Then you want to loop through the phone array and add the phone number to the new PhoneNumbers table checking that it doesn't already exist. If it already exists then you need to grab the PhoneNumbers Id.

Then, using the new Hotel_PhoneNumbers table, create a new row containing the PhoneNumber Id and the Hotel Id. This links the phone number(s) to the hotel.

By doing this, the PhoneNumbers table will only contain unique phone numbers, but can be linked to multiple hotels.

I can't specifically give you the code to do this as I don't know how you communicate with your database. I use Laravel and Eloquent, so it might look something like this;

```
$hotels = Hotel::all();

foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    $numbers = explode(',' $hotel->phone);

    if (count($numbers) > 0) {
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            // See if the PhoneNumber already exists in the database
            $phoneNumber = PhoneNumber::where('telephone', $number);

            // If the phone number doesn't exist, we need to add the number to the database
            if (is_null($phoneNumber)) {
                // Create a new phone number
                $phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
                $phoneNumber->telephone = $number;
                $phoneNumber->save();
            }

            // Check if the hotel is already linked to the phone number in the database
            $hotelPhoneNumber = HotelPhoneNumber::where('hotel_id', $hotel->id)->where('phone_id', $phoneNumber->id);

            // If the hotel isn't linked to the number, create the link
            if (is_null($hotelPhoneNumber)) {
                $hotelPhoneNumber = new HotelPhoneNumber();
                $hotelPhoneNumber->hotel_id = $hotel->id;
                $hotelPhoneNumber->phone_id = $phoneNumber->id;
                $hotelPhoneNumber->save();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```